# Slack automate calendar events

Tags: automation, slack, slack-api

I'm looking for a way to automate the creation of calendar events. I'm part of multiple spaces in my school and they keep on posting some events that are happening on a regular basis.

I was wondering is there's a way to automate these calendar events. I want to write a script with Slack api's that can read the messages from all the spaces I'm part of and scan them to see if there's any event related information and create a new calendar event in my google calendars. I want to run this at the end of the day on all the messages from all the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import json
import pprint

import time
import parsedatetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError

from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def get_google_service():
    creds = None
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    return build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)


def send_google_calendar_invite(service, channel_name, start_time, end_time):
    try:
        # f = open("template.json", "r")
        # template_data = f.read()
        template_data = '''
                        {
                            "summary": "event_name",
                            "location": "event_location",
                            "description": "event_description",
                            "start": {
                                "dateTime": "event_start_time",
                                "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
                            },
                            "end": {
                                "dateTime": "event_end_time",
                                "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
                            }
                        }
                        '''
        template_data = template_data.replace('event_name', channel_name)
        template_data = template_data.replace('event_location', channel_name+'-meeting')
        template_data = template_data.replace('event_description', channel_name+'-desrpition')
        template_data = template_data.replace('event_start_time', start_time)
        template_data = template_data.replace('event_end_time', end_time)
        json_object = json.loads(template_data)
        json_formatted_str = json.dumps(json_object, indent=2)
        print(json_formatted_str)

        event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=json_object).execute()
        print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))

    except HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


def read_slack_messages():
    channel_id = "C04QL76V21X"

    try:
        lastHourDateTime = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)
        client = WebClient(token=open("secrets.txt", "r").read())
        conversation_history = client.conversations_history(channel=channel_id, oldest=time.mktime(lastHourDateTime.timetuple()))
        channel_info_result = client.conversations_info(channel=channel_id)

        channel_name = channel_info_result['channel']['name']
        conversation_messages = conversation_history["messages"]
        print("{} messages found in {}".format(len(conversation_messages), id))
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace();

        
        service = get_google_service()
        for message in conversation_messages[:2]:
            chat_message = message['text']

            try:
                cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
                dates = cal.parse(chat_message)
                print(dates)
                start_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%000:00', (dates[0]))
                end_time = start_time[:11]+f"{int(start_time[11:13])+1:02}"+start_time[13:]
                print(chat_message, ' : ', start_time, ' ||| ', end_time)

                send_google_calendar_invite(service, channel_name, start_time, end_time)

            except TypeError as e: 
                print(' : Nope : ', e);

    except SlackApiError as e:
        print("Error getting conversation: {}".format(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_slack_messages()
```